# dateFromString give error when string is 20130331

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsdate, nsdateformatter

i have and function that convert string to date. and its working very fine but when i try to convert 20130331 the application crashs.
and here my code

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyyMMdd"];
NSDate *date = [dateFormat dateFromString:dateStr];
NSLog(@"before %@ dateStr %@",date,dateStr);
```

the log is is following

```
2013-01-02 17:56:04.402 jana2ez[6067:11303] before 2013-03-28 22:00:00 +0000 dateStr 20130329 
2013-01-02 17:56:04.498 jana2ez[6067:11303] before 2013-03-29 22:00:00 +0000 dateStr 20130330 
2013-01-02 17:56:04.626 jana2ez[6067:11303] before (null) dateStr 20130331
```

any idea??

Comment: Post more code. What's around the above code? How is dateStr set up?

Comment: Of note could be that the date is being parsed incorrectly to begin with. Without seeing more code, we can't see why, but 20130329 is being parsed to March 28th, 2013, at 10 PM. Are you releasing the DateFormatter at the end of this block of code?

Comment: @Echihl - That's the time zone offset.

Comment: I'm betting that the formatter is not defaulting to a Gregorian calendar, due to locale.

Comment: `NSLog(@"The calendar type is %@", dateFormat.calendar.calendarIdentifier);`

Comment: my calendar type is gregorian

Comment: @occuls the date star is a string generated from 3 integer (year, month, day), every thing is fine unless the 20130331

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After hours of bad results, finally I found a solution inspired from @Echihl's comment.

I changed the time in the date so the date will be parsed to same date found in `dateStr`.

```
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyyMMdd HHmm"];
    NSDate *date = [dateFormat dateFromString:dateStr];
    NSLog(@"before %@ dateStr %@",date,dateStr);
```

My output becomes

```
    before 2013-03-31 05:00:00 +0000 dateStr 20130331 0800
```

Previously 20130329 was parsed to March 28th, 2013, at 10 PM

Comment: But previously you didn't show the extra digits in dateStr.  You must always show the full data in situations like this.

Comment: previously wasn't use the extra digits. it was '20130331'

Answer (score 1):

```
NSCalendar* gregCalendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
[dateFormat setCalendar:gregCalendar];
```

Comment: unfortunately it didn't works, my default calendar is Gregorian